# How to set up Spark on multi-node Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I would like to install Hadoop HDFS and Spark on multi-node cluster.

I was able to successfully install and configure Hadoop on multi-node cluster. I have also installed and configured Spark on master node.

I have doubts that I have to configure the spark in slaves as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have doubt that I have to configure the spark in slaves as well?

You should not. You're done. You did more than you had to to submit Spark applications to Hadoop YARN (which I *concluded* is the cluster manager).

Spark is a library for distributed computations on massive datasets and as such it belongs solely to your Spark applications (not any cluster you may use).

Time to `spark-submit` Spark applications!